# Cache images served in http instead of https

Tags: views, theming, caching, ssl

It's more than one year I have changed my website from http to https. There is still pages that are not correctly served by drupal.
On some pages there are still images that are served by **http** instead of **https**, example:

> http://domain.com/site/sites/default/files/ctools/style/_temporary/2d16a055ca7679c4c225b905b9c58939/rounded-shadow-background.png

As this page/image is created live and the image belongs to panels module, I have no idea where to search for this problem, drupal? ctools? panels?
I use the last drupal version 7 with panels, ctools and zen theme.

All caches and views were cleared many times.
Any help is welcome, thanks.

Comment: I think this is something that you will do through the .htaccess file

Comment: I don't think so because my .htaccess contains  
`RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
 RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]`